# Node Express API routing, Id of parent resource not available in req.params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, routeparams

My problem is that I don't get the id of parent resource in req.params in routes of subresources. Come with me ... I'll show you ...

Here's the relevant parts in my code:

```
 - routes/
    - index.js
    - countries.js
    - cities.js
 - controllers/
    - cities.js
```

index.js

```
let router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/countries', require('./countries'));
router.use('/countries/:countryId/cities', require('./cities'));

module.exports = router;
```

routes/countries.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const countries = require('../controllers/countries');

router.post('/', countries.create);

router.get('/', countries.readAll);

router.get('/:_id', countries.readById);

router.patch('/:_id', countries.updateById);

router.delete('/:_id', countries.deleteById);

module.exports = router;
```

routes/cities.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const cities = require('../controllers/cities');

router.get('/', cities.readAll);

router.get('/:_id', cities.readById);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/cities.js

```
module.exports.readAll = async function (req, res, next)
{
    return res.json(req.params);
};

module.exports.readById = async function (req, res, next)
{
    return res.json(req.params);
};
```

Now, the problem is as follows:

If I call the following API:

GET countries/1/cities

The result is {} 
When it should actually send me back  {"countryId":"1"}

Also, when I call the following API:

GET countries/1/cities/2

The result is {"_id": "2"}
When it should actually send me back {"countryId":"1", "_id": "2"}

So the problem is for some reason, the id of the parent resource (countryId) is not accessible in the controller of the child resource.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this SO question
[Nested routes in express, where a parent route includes a param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140273/nested-routes-in-express-where-a-parent-route-includes-a-param)

```
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```