# root parameter not appearing in req.params

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following basic Express application:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

router.get("/:uuid", (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.params);
});

// Force all requests to provide a "base" parameter.
app.use("/:base", router);

// Middleware to validate that the base parameter was provided.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.params.base) return res.status(400).json({
        error: "No base provided."
    });
    next();
});

app.listen(port);
```

In this application, I've noticed that, for some reason, Express *refuses* to put the `base` parameter in `req.params`. It does this irregardless of what it is named.

As a result, a request to `/foo/bar` will *always* result in:

```
{
    "uuid": "bar"
}
```

Why is this? I know that Express is receiving the parameter, since the middleware to validate said parameter will display an error if one is not provided.

Comment: Not an answer but your _middleware_ will never run unless you register it **before** the router

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested routes in express, where a parent route includes a param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140273/nested-routes-in-express-where-a-parent-route-includes-a-param). _TL;DR_ when creating your router, use the option `mergeParams: true`